# How to remove event handler that is assigned through style

Tags: wpf, events, styles, runtime

I've created a WPF window. In that I've created style for a textbox which have size information as well as some eventsetters; Then, I've created some textboxes assigning the above style.

Now for one case I need to remove events of that textbox. But I cant do that.
Even though I do the following the event is not detached. It still there.
txt9.PreviewLostKeyboardFocus -= txt9_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus;

This occurs only when the event is attached in the style itself.
If it were within the TextBox control the event detaches fine.

My Code:
XAML:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
         <Style x:Key="txtStyle11" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="35"/>
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewLostKeyboardFocus" Handler="txt9_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid MinWidth="50">
    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource txtStyle11}" x:Name="txt9"/>
    </Grid>
```

CS:

```
     public MainWindow()
     {
     txt9.PreviewLostKeyboardFocus -= txt9_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus;
     }
```

Comment: Try removing the event in Window_Loaded event. The styles are first applied to the textbox when the window is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Hi we cannot Unsubscribe events whcih are subscribed in EventSetter, because
internally EventSetter class becomes immutable and so the properties of the 
EventSetter object cannot be modified. Below is the sample which I tried to 
illustrate the same. This sample throws exception when we try to change the 
property of setterbase class

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    KeyboardFocusChangedEventHandler mydelegate, emptydelegate;
    EventSetter eventSetter;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        emptydelegate  = delegate(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        };

        mydelegate = delegate(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("My Own Event is still Unsubscribed");
        };
        eventSetter = new EventSetter();
        eventSetter.Event = TextBox.PreviewLostKeyboardFocusEvent;
        eventSetter.Handler = mydelegate;
        Style myStyle = new System.Windows.Style(txt9.GetType()); 
        myStyle.Setters.Add(eventSetter);
        txt9.Style = myStyle;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        eventSetter.Handler= emptydelegate;
    }
}
```